# SBE protocol support in grpc/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, grpc, grpc-node

We are planning to use grpc for web ui and server communication. We also intend to use SBE as communication protocol. I have 2 questions in this regard

1. Can we use SBE protocol with grpc instead of protobuf.
2. Do we have support in JavaScript/typescript to encode/decode SBE messages.

Appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see issue using another encoding withing protobuf. You will have to send sbe encoded message as byte payload and the decode it with directbuffer etc.

In regards to typescript support there is none that I am aware see this post
https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/issues/116

Comment: https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I have a working TypeScript codec generator. It is still work in progress. You can check it out
https://github.com/rafalpiotrowski/simple-binary-encoding
branch: typescript-support

If you want to get involved get in thouch.